# td changes color on echo result

Tags: php, html, css

Here is part of the code I am working on. All this has to do is, if the ping succeeds it changes the first td to green but if the ping failed its red.

The problem I'm having is that I can use images or any kind of method to display it and it works but all I want is to change the `background-color` of the `td` before the IP address. Am I doing something wrong here?

```
<table  height="630" class="table">
    <tr>
        <td width="5" >
        <?php
            $str = exec("ping -n 1 -w 1 10.9.1.1", $input, $result);
            if ($result == 0){ echo "<style='background-color:green;'>";}
            else{ echo "<style='background-color:red;'>";}
        ?>
        </td>
        <td width="50">10.9.1.1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: you need to use `<td style="background-color:green;">` for an inline per element style, or use your logic to set a `class` attribute in which you can define a style sheet rule.

Comment: but if i use the <td style="background-color:green;"> in the PHP code it only created a new td and not changing the current td

Comment: Then you're doing something terribly wrong.

Answer (score 1):

`style` has to be an attribute of the `td` tag, not a tag by itself. So you shouldn't close the `td` tag  at first, then echo the `style` attribute (without the opening `<` you have in your code) and then close the `td` tag:

```
<table  height="630" class="table">
    <tr>
        <td width="5" 
        <?php
           $str = exec("ping -n 1 -w 1 10.9.1.1", $input, $result);
           if ($result == 0){echo "style='background-color:green;'>";}
           else{ echo "style='background-color:red;'>";}
        ?>
        </td>
        <td width="50">10.9.1.1</td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

A `<style='background-color:green;'>` doesn't exist as single style tag.

Just insert the CSS rule into the style attribute of your `<td>`:

```html
<table  height="630" class="table">
  <tr>
    <td width="5" style="
      <?php
      $str = exec('ping -n 1 -w 1 10.9.1.1', $input, $result);
      if ($result == 0){
        echo 'background-color:green;';
      } else {
        echo 'background-color:red;';
      }
      ?>
    ">
    </td>
    <td width="50">10.9.1.1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Style needs to be added to the td not on its own unless in the head section. So instead you can use the if statements to produce different td's or classes or anything really but here's an example of td's

```
<table  height="630" class="table">
  <tr>
    <?php
    $str = exec("ping -n 1 -w 1 10.9.1.1", $input, $result);
    if ($result == 0):?>
        <td width="5" style="background-color:green;">
    <?php else :?>
        <td width="5" style="background-color:red;">
    <?php endif;>
        </td>
    <td width="50">10.9.1.1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```